# Slow INSERT - MS SQL - execution time of every step

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, management-studio-express

I've got an INSERT in stored procedure:
`INSERT INTO t1 SELECT TOP 3 x FROM t2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t3 inner join t4 on t4.z = t3.z)`

My question is:
Is it possible, to get execution time of every step in this insert?

I'm using SQL SERVER EXPRESS 2008.

Comment: Look at the execution plan, it'll give you comparative time of execution for each step at DB engine level. On the other hand, you can try creating index on t4.z and t3.z to make this query run faster if haven't already.

Comment: The actual execution plan will reveal details of the "steps" SQL Server uses to execute the query, including costs, resource usage, and times. However, some plan operators are blocking and others not so a per-operator execution time isn't always particularly useful.

Comment: In execution plan I've found, that 'Clustered Index Scan" has "Cost 93%". How should I understand it ? Do it mean, that it takes more than 90% of time?

Comment: You have a clustered index while you are examining single columns from t3 and t4. You may wish to re-examine the index definition.

Comment: It's not a execution plan issue, it's bad SQL.

    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t3 inner join t4 on t4.z = t3.z)

You don't reference any of the other tables in this predicate.  I doubt this is getting optimised out, might be worth starting by fixing that.